# Python slicing numpy array with index tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, tuples

I want to slice an N-dimensional numpy array `a` using an N-1-dimensional index tuple `b`. Below is a case with N = 4:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(20,1,5,4)
b1 = (0,0,0)
b2 = (0,3,2)

# want to get the slice c = a[:,b2[0],b2[1],b2[2]] without explicitly writing all N-1 elements of b2

c = a[:,b1] # no error message, but gives a[:,[b1[0],b1[1],b1[2]],:,:]
c = a[:,b2] # error message (because b2[1] = 3 larger than a.shape[1])
```

What is the correct way to "unpack" the tuple index elements into the different dimensions? I tried using the asterisk operator (`*b`), but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
a[(..., *b1)]
```

This boils down to calling the `__getitem__` method manually with a variable argument in the index tuple:

```py
In [23]: a.__getitem__((..., *b1))
Out[23]: 
array([0.93049554, 0.63858628, 0.31665933, 0.15048072, 0.17083849,
       0.34621308, 0.66980288, 0.75191251, 0.05844084, 0.16715787,
       0.80409005, 0.64181912, 0.76463963, 0.75616746, 0.44955961,
       0.19034925, 0.8841084 , 0.54450091, 0.02033021, 0.21275405])

In [21]: a[:, 0, 0, 0]
Out[21]: 
array([0.93049554, 0.63858628, 0.31665933, 0.15048072, 0.17083849,
       0.34621308, 0.66980288, 0.75191251, 0.05844084, 0.16715787,
       0.80409005, 0.64181912, 0.76463963, 0.75616746, 0.44955961,
       0.19034925, 0.8841084 , 0.54450091, 0.02033021, 0.21275405])
```

Be aware though that the usage of the ellipsis (`...`) has a slightly more general meaning.  Otherwise, you have to construct the `:` slice manually:

```py
In [20]: a.__getitem__((slice(None), *b1))
Out[20]: 
array([0.93049554, 0.63858628, 0.31665933, 0.15048072, 0.17083849,
       0.34621308, 0.66980288, 0.75191251, 0.05844084, 0.16715787,
       0.80409005, 0.64181912, 0.76463963, 0.75616746, 0.44955961,
       0.19034925, 0.8841084 , 0.54450091, 0.02033021, 0.21275405])
```

Comment: This is no different to doing `a[(slice(None), *b1)]`

Comment: Uh, that's much nicer. I always forget the minutiae of `__getitem__`... make it an answer!

Comment: (Or rather, I find the Julia conventions much more intuitive, where `getindex` takes a vararg of all dimensions and `:` is an object on its own.)

Comment: Nah, it's all yours. What I was thinking actually was that advanced indexing requires tuples for each dimension, which is more cumbersome than what you have here. And in the case of one element per axis, it reduces down to what you got.

Comment: @phipsgabler: With `a[[0,0,3,2]]`, the indices are interpreted to refer to the first dimension only, but with `a[(0,0,3,2)]` they refer to the four separate dimensions. So why is the behavior of `a[[slice(None),0,3,2]]` and `a[(slice(None),0,3,2)]` identical? Does Python recognize they cannot refer to the first dimension only, because the `slice(None)` already selects all of them and it sees the `0,3,2`?

Comment: @bproxauf That's not Python, but Numpy's implementation of `__getitem__`. They do some fancy dispatch on types and contents. But you do get a warning: _Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result._